# Combine arrays and merge keys together for table output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm fetching multiple data into arrays. Now I want to combine the arrays together and merge them with their symbol keys.
The idea is to output it inside a table like this to compare the diferent prices:

```
Name|Price1|Price2|Price3|
CAT |  10  |  20  |  15  |
DOG |  15  |  25  |  13  |
etc |..    |..
```

The arrays are formatted like this:

**Array 1:**

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "CAT",
    "price": "10"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "DOG ",
    "price": "15"
  }
]
```

**Array 2:**

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "CAT",
    "price": "20"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "DOG ",
    "price": "25"
  }
]
```

**Array 3:**

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "CAT",
    "price": "15"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "DOG ",
    "price": "13"
  }
]
```

My attempt:

```
var combine = Object.entries(array1, array2, array3)
      .map((k, v) => {
        Object.assign(
          { symbol: k.symbol },
          { price: v.price }
        )
      })
```

How can I achieve this using ES6?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Just make an object where keys are the symbols and the value is an array of prices.

Comment: @Mark_M: yes, that's very easy to do with `reduce`.  But there is still work to do to turn that to the output required.  I would like to see some attempt in the question before making suggestions.

Comment: @ScottSauyet added attempt.

Comment: `Object.entries` won't help with much of anything here.  You can use either my version `[arr1, arr2, arr3]` or others' `[...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3]` to combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply looking for a way to transform this data into a more useful format, the following function would yield:

```
{CAT: [10, 20, 15], DOG: [15, 25, 13]}
```

You could then use that to create your table.  If you're looking for help with turning that into a display format, please either clarify here or ask another question.

```js
const makeTable = (...data) => data.reduce(
  (tbl, arr) => arr.reduce(
    (tbl, {price, symbol}) => 
      ((tbl[symbol] || (tbl[symbol] = [])).push(price), tbl),
    tbl
  ), {}
)

const arr1 = [{"price": "10", "symbol": "CAT"}, {"price": "15", "symbol": "DOG "}]
const arr2 = [{"price": "20", "symbol": "CAT"}, {"price": "25", "symbol": "DOG "}]
const arr3 = [{"price": "15", "symbol": "CAT"}, {"price": "13", "symbol": "DOG "}]

console.log(makeTable(arr1, arr2, arr3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are many scenarios where you want to pass data around, and the best plan is to convert one data format to another. If, however, you are just making a table from this data, you end up iterating through your data once to make the new format and then iterating through that new format to make your table. You look at every piece of data twice.

You can just make the table while iterating the first time. Whether this is a good idea depends on information not in the question, but I thought I'd share in case it's helpful:

```js
let arr1 = [{  "symbol": "CAT",  "price": "10"},{  "symbol": "DOG ",  "price": "15"}]
let arr2 = [{  "symbol": "CAT",  "price": "20"},{  "symbol": "DOG ",  "price": "25"}]
let arr3 = [{  "symbol": "CAT",  "price": "15"},{  "symbol": "DOG ",  "price": "13"}]

let arrays = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3]
let table = document.getElementById('theTable')

arrays.reduce((rows, {symbol, price}) => {
    let row = rows[symbol]
    if (!row) { // haven't seen this symbol? Make a new row
      row = document.createElement("tr")
      let data = document.createElement("td")
      data.innerHTML = symbol
      row.appendChild(data)
      table.appendChild(row)
      rows[symbol] = row
    }
    let data = document.createElement("td")
    data.innerHTML = price
    row.appendChild(data)
    return rows
}, {})
```

```css
td {
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="theTable"></table>
```

Comment: I would only worry about the multiple passes through the data if profiling showed there was a performance issue in such code.  I think it's much cleaner to do as much data transformation as possible in small, focused functions that are easy to read, then only once all the transformations are done do I run any display code.

Comment: I don't disagree with you @ScottSauyet — but consider what the code will actually look like if you just need to make a table from this data and you start with a data processing loop first: you'll first process the data into another format, then you'll take that data  you made and make another pass with a function that will look pretty much like the above. My point is that either way you are making a table-creating loop over some data, so why have twice as much code unless you're getting some other benefit from the first pass (which no-doubt often happens).

Answer (score 1):

You should first merge the 3 arrays and then use `reduce` to create the object you want

```js
const array1 = [{"symbol": "CAT","price": "10"},{"symbol": "DOG ","price": "15"}],
      array2 = [{"symbol": "CAT","price": "20"},{"symbol": "DOG ","price": "25"}],
      array3 = [{"symbol": "CAT","price": "15"},{"symbol": "DOG ","price": "13"}];

const combined = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3].reduce((p, {
  symbol,
  price
}) => {
  const current = p[symbol];
  if (!current) p[symbol] = [price];
  if (current) p[symbol].push(price);
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(combined)
```

Comment: I don't think it's the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

```
let finalArray=[...a1,...a2,...a3];
let obj={};

finalArray.forEach(element=>{
   obj.hasOwnProperty(element.symbol) ? 
      obj[element.symbol].push(element.price) :
          obj[element.symbol] =[element.price];
});
```

`obj` will finally contain the following `Object`:

```
{CAT: [10, 20, 15], DOG: [15, 25, 13]}
```